# xcode 6 Cannot invoke 'stringFromDate' with an argument list of type '(NSData)'

Tags: swift

I am building single App for weight and this is the code

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var appdel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as! AppDelegate
    var context = appdel.managedObjectContext

let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Wights", inManagedObjectContext: context!)

    var newwight = Wights(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context!)

    // fill the coredata

    newwight.wight = textField.text

    if (Uinits.on) {

      newwight.wight = "Lb"

    } else {

        newwight.units = "Kg"


    }

    let dataFormatter = NSDateFormatter ()

    var locale : NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

    var formatstring : NSString = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("EdMM h: mm a", options: 0, locale: locale)!


    dataFormatter.dateFormat = formatstring as String
    newwight.data = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(NSData())`
```

But I have the problem in this line:

```
newwight.data = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(NSData())
```

Cannot invoke `stringFromDate` with an argument list of type `(NSData)`

Answer (score 2):

Date and data are two very different things.

In the same way, NSDate and NSData are two very different things.

Comment: Not that it matters, but weights and wights are also different things.

Comment: yes  as you said i have error  with the letters its NSDate thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use "NSDate()" instead of "NSData()"? It worked for me.

```
dataFormatter.dateFormat = formatstring as String  
var newwightData = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) //"Sun, 06/21, 11:32 PM"
```